# JavaScript mouse movement causing lag?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, lag

I am very new to coding in JavaScript and confused!

When you first run this code everything works fine. However, once you move for a little bit you start to realize it gets more and more laggy to where it is almost unplayable.

What is causing this?

How do I fix it?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rotate</title>
    <script src="Tank.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #ccc" width="700" height="500">
    </canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var mouseX, mouseY;

        function Tank(x, y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.angle;
        }

        Tank.prototype.draw = function(){
            context.save();
            context.translate(this.x, this.y);
            context.rotate(this.angle);
            context.fillStyle = "green";
            context.arc(0,0,30,0,2*Math.PI);
            context.fill();
            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.fillRect(0,-10,50,20);
            context.restore();
        }

        Tank.prototype.update = function(mouseX, mouseY){
            var dx = mouseX - this.x;
            var dy = mouseY - this.y;
            this.angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        }

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);

        function mouseMove(evt){
            mouseX = evt.x;
            mouseY = evt.y;     
        }

        var tank = new Tank(350, 250);

        function gameLoop(){
            context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            tank.draw();
            tank.update(mouseX, mouseY);
        }

        setInterval(gameLoop,20);   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: gameLoop is being called every 20 milliseconds - that's not good it's filling up memory.

Comment: I'm guessing you're coming at this from a background in game coding? The web isn't really like that and you have to adjust accordingly. Alternatively, check out [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API) which makes better use of the hardware for games

Comment: @garrettlynch Well, 20 ms is not that much if the code is not hard and the computer has a decent CPU. Most browsers can go up to 16 ms (60 FPS).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Even if you change the setInterval to a higher number you get the same problem!

Comment: Please, Fiddle it so we can test and such. And clean your indentaion. Is a bit messy and is  must. I'll try to help if you fiddle it for me.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mmkzes7n/1/ here is the fiddle!

Comment: You should edit your question with the fiddle, and fix the indentation both in the question and the fiddle.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed this or not, and it's not related to the question at hand here, but I think you have some aim issues. If I point the mouse pointer at the very north/east/south/west corners of the green circle, I'd expect the red rectangle to be totally vertical/horizontal, but it's pretty far off. Check the points you're calculating the angle from. EDIT: never mind; it was the padding around the canvas which caused the issue. No issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/mmkzes7n/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`context.beginPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) before starting new paths. Without this, your calls to [`arc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) build up the same path with more and more subpaths each frame, and so each successive frame is drawing a more complex shape. It's also taking more and more memory as time goes on.

Fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmkzes7n/2/

In this fiddle I also changed out `setInterval` for [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which I think is a good idea. You can read up about that and decide whether you want to make this same change or not. (You could then enhance it to only request an animation frame if a redraw is actually needed. At present this is only if the mouse position has moved, but as the game evolves I'm sure there will be more to it than that.)